# Installing a generic Android OS

Tags: android

I have a tablet with Android 2.2 installed on it. The manufacturer doesn't have an upgrade OS and if possible I would like to upgrade it to a higher version of Android (any higher version would do) so that I can use it for testing purposes. Is it possible to install a generic version of Android on a device or would it never run at all? Where would I even get such a generic version? In addition to that, would it also support the camera?

Comment: http://cyanogenmod.com can be a solution..

Comment: What do you mean by generic? Only the latest versions(4.2.2) support all the features of android. You can install custom ROMs for the higher versions of android in your tablet, but do it at your own risk

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Google provide a generic version of their OS to manufacturers who then customize it? So technically, the generic version should run on any device should it not?

Comment: try http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/rooting-and-roms/how-to-find-custom-roms-for-your-android-phone/

Comment: Try the above link.. this will solve your problem

Comment: No, if you build Android from source and try to install it, it won't work unless you have a Nexus device. http://source.android.com/devices/index.html

Comment: This question does not belong here... it belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a raw android rom in your device if you are lucky and get a `custom rom` for your device.

You can try to search your device [Here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Devices#vendor=;)

For installing a `custom rom` first you have to `root` you device and then you have to install a [custom recovery](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-a-custom-recovery-to-an-android-phone-device/). 
Then you can install your `custom rom`.

There is a very less chance to brick you tablet if you find a custom rom which is made specifically for your device.